# Notice: Undefined offset using foreach with xml

Tags: php, xml, foreach

I've been searching through previous questions for the past hour, so if this exists somewhere else, sorry, but I didn't find it.  I'm pretty new to PHP, so forgive me if it's a newbie question.  I searched through Google, too.

I'm trying to automate getting the lat/long information from airnav.com for various airports for map updates.  I've got an XML file with the airport codes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<AIRPORTS xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <AIRPORT>MXA</AIRPORT>
  <AIRPORT>SDM</AIRPORT>
</AIRPORTS>
```

My PHP is:

```
<?php
  $xml=simplexml_load_file("airports.xml");

  foreach($xml->AIRPORT as $arpt)
  {
    if (preg_match('#[0-9]#', $arpt)){
      $arptName = $arpt;}

    else{
      $arptName = "K" . $arpt;}

    $content = file_get_contents("http://www.airnav.com/airport/" . $arptName);

    preg_match('#([0-9]{2,2}\.[0-9]{1,})\s\/\s(\-[0-9]{2,2}\.[0-9]{1,})#', $content, $arptmatch);

    $lat = $arptmatch[1]; //ERROR HERE (line 27)
    $long = $arptmatch[2]; //AND HERE (line 28)

    echo "Airport: $arpt\nLat: $lat\nLong: $long\n";
  }
?>
```

This works just fine for the first airport, I get this:

```
Airport: MXA Lat: 35.8944444 Long: -90.1545833
```

Which, when I go to the site and check is correct.  But for the second airport, I get:

```
Airport: SDM Lat: Long:
```

Along with the following errors:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /home/a5308473/public_html/phpStuff/readFromAirNav.html on line 27
Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in /home/a5308473/public_html/phpStuff/readFromAirNav.html on line 28
```

I can't seem to find any way to fix this.  Anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: Maybe your `preg_match()` is not finding a match?  You should check return results of `preg_match()` before trying to operate against them. So something like `$result = preg_match(...); if (1 === $result) { // you have a match $lat = ...; $long = ...; }`

Comment: I just want to point out that your RE will only match on negative longitudes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the coordinates for SDM are `32.5722722 / -116.9801611`. In the second part of your regular expression, `116` must be between 2 and 2 characters `{2,2}`. Change it so that it matches 2 to 3 characters, `{2,3}`. If you are only using United States coordinates then {2,3} will work, but outside of the United States you could run into coordinates that have a single digit integer-part. `{1,3}` would be match the integer-part of any longitude and `{1,2}` would be a match for the integer-part of any latitude.

Your regular expression should be

```
([0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,})\s\/\s(\-[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,})
```

Because your regular expression doesn't match anything, the results are a 0 length array and your index offset is greater than the length of the array.

Additionally, `{2,2}` can be written as `{2}` and `{1,}` can be written as `+`

Comment: Yep, that's it. I guess I'd been looking at the code for too long.  Thank you!

Comment: Yes, there are some tricks for effective troubleshooting, for example using a step-debugger and looking just before the error comes if the variables contain what they have (because you can inspect the program when it runs).

Answer (score 1):

You're simply assuming that preg_match did find something, and blindly barge on ahead, even if no matches were actually made.

Try

```
if (preg_match(...)) {
    $lat = $arptmatch[1];
    $long = $arptmatch[2];
} else {
    $lat = 'n/a';
    $long = 'n/a';
}
```

instead.

Comment: I hadn't really thought of that.  Good point that I need a check.  Thanks.